# ¿Mala optimización de sitio en React/NextJs?

Tags: reactjs

Soy relativamente nuevo tanto en React como NextJs. **Estoy realizando un proyecto y a la hora de medir el rendimiento con la herramienta 'Google PageSpeed Insights' me encuentro con que el rendimiento es pésimo**. Me indica que hay scripts de js (externos) que bloquean por varios segundos la página, pero lo cierto es que dichos scripts están siendo cargados de manera asíncrona para evitar eso mismo.

Cuando veo los tiempos de carga en la consola de Chrome, veo que a veces tarda 180ms en cargar el DOM y 900ms en hacer Load, y otras veces, tarda mucho más, dejo algunas pruebas:
[image: 1]
[image: 2]

**En la práctica, si abren el sitio van a ver que es navegable e interactivo en muy poco tiempo, realmente carga muy rápido. Incluso con 'Fast 3G' tarda 700ms en cargar el DOM.
Mi inquietud principal es: ¿Qué es lo que está mal?, ¿Cómo se puede optimizar mejor (o correctamente) el sitio?**

Enlace al sitio: https://1tienda.online/

Repositorio GitHub: https://github.com/gabenitez0/1tiendaonline-nextjs

PageSpeed Insight: [Ver](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=es&url=http%3A%2F%2F1tienda.online%2F)

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Si, bueno, esto de optimización en el frontend es todo un arte. Al menos yo encuentro que tu página carga en un tiempo razonablemente bueno. Personalmente evaluaría el mejorar la carga por un par de ms. versus el tiempo que te vas a tomar para investigar el cómo hacerlo y no se si valga la pena el esfuerzo para un landing page. Quizás lo consideraría en un página donde haya mayor interacción por parte del usuario o que exista un manejo más intensivo de js, manipulación de DOM, etc.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte. Si requiere de mucho trabajo creo que como dices, no vale la pena. Tal vez si tiene que ver con la importación dinámica de next o algo de eso (o no tan complejo) me podría servir.